# Using the same vector without the resize() part

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I have a question about `std::vector` -

```
vector<int> vec(1,0);

while(//something_1)
{
    while(//something_2)
    {
       ...
       vec.pushback(var)
       ...
    }

    process(vec.size()); //every iteration- different size

    vec.clear();
    vec.resize(0,0);
}
```

On this case - every `vec.push_back(var)` there is reallocation of a new array with size bigger by one than the former array.

My question is - if there is a way using one vector, so after the inner `while(//something_2)`, the `vec.push_back(var)` command will push back from the first cell of `vec`? instead of using `vec.clear()` and `vec.resize(0,0)`? so I could save the resize part and the reallocation.

The size of the vector is important for the function `process(vec.size())`

Thanks.

Comment: If that's the case, then your `vector` implementation is horribly broken. `push_back` should make it grow exponentially, and it shouldn't need to reallocate after `clear` until it grows beyond its capacity (which will be at least as large as the old size). How are you determining that it grows by one for each `push_back`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) first time if you know beforehand approximately how much your vector could grow.

[clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) `Leaves the capacity() of the vector unchanged.` Which means that `push_back` & and other modifiers will use the same memory.

`resize(0,0)` should be removed.